# Extracting EPOCH value from timestamp without timezone in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am getting the following error running this PostgreSQL query. Can anyone tell me how to correct this query?

SQL error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "fitacf_data"
> LINE 1: ...fitacf_data.num_pts, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP fitacf_dat...
>                                                              ^
> ```

```
SELECT fitacf_data.file_date, fitacf_data.num_pts, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP fitacf_data.time), fitacf_data.stcode FROM fitacf_data WHERE fitacf_data.file_date BETWEEN '2017-04-14 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-14 23:59:59' AND fitacf_data.stcode = 'pgr';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `fitacf_data.time` already is a `timestamp` leave the `TIMESTAMP` keyword away, that's for literals.

```
...
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM fitacf_data.time)
...
```